# not all code paths return a value error on web method

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, webmethod

I have a web method function has checks if a name exists in the database but I am getting the error:

> Error 114 'lookups_Creditor.CheckIfNameExists(string)': not all code
>   paths return a value

Here is the web method:

```
[WebMethod]
    public static bool CheckIfNameExists(string Name)//error on this line
    {
        try
        {
           Creditor.CheckIfNameCreditorExists(Company.Current.CompanyID, Name);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

And here is the search function for the sql:

```
public static string CheckIfNameCreditorExists(int CompanyID, string Name)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        string accNo = "";
        string sql = "proc_CheckIfACCreditorExists";

        string query = "SELECT c.* " +
            " FROM Creditor c " +
            " WHERE c.Company_ID = " + CompanyID + " AND c.Name LIKE '" + Name + "' ";


        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter(query, DataUtils.ConnectionStrings["TAT"]))
        {
            adapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            adapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = query;
            adapter.Fill(dt);
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
               accNo = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[0]["AccoutCode"]);
            }

        }
        return accNo;
    }
```

I am trying to create a method that searches for the name in the database. If the name exists, then return the account code associated with that name. I will the display a message on the screen telling the user that the name already exists on the account ABC.

Comment: well it has a return type of bool, and you don't return a bool anywhere... what do you expect?

Answer (score 0):

You have written the return type as Bool and you are not returning anything.

If you don't have anything to return then just make that return type to Void.

By the method name it indicates you should return either "True" or "False".

The error just indicates that, you should return something when you have a return type other than void in your methods.

Comment: judging by the method name the OP does want to return something... so the void part is probably irrelavent

Comment: Yeah that's true by the name it clearly shows you should return something either true or false, just add a return type to the method.

Answer (score 0):

```
[WebMethod]
public static bool CheckIfNameExists(string Name)//error on this line
{
    bool Result = false;
    try
    {
       Result = Creditor.CheckIfNameCreditorExists(Company.Current.CompanyID, Name) != "";

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }

    return Result
}
```

Comment: If doing this I would also have a Result = false; in the catch

Comment: not needed because initialized to false. It can only become true if no exception occurs and Check <> ""

Comment: @GuidoG - `bool` is anyways initialized to false.

Answer (score 0):

Your method is supposed to return bool, yet you don't return anything. 
You need to rewrite it something like this:

```
[WebMethod]
public static bool CheckIfNameExists(string Name)
{
    bool res = false;
    try
    {
       // Check your string result if it's null or empty
       // and store the result in local variable
       res = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Creditor.CheckIfNameCreditorExists(Company.Current.CompanyID, Name));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Do your handling here
    }

    return res;
}
```

Comment: This is the more correct form... except it will need negating. String.IsNullOrEmpty returns true if it is null or empty as the name suggests